# win32 project designer

Tags: c++

anyone know of some good software that can help me design the form for my win32 project?

or is there a way to get the form designer in visual c++ for win32 projects?

Answer (score 1):

VS contains a dialog editor. To access it add a resource (.rc) file to your project, open that file and select "Insert Dialog" from the Resource View context menu.

If you don't want to use a dialog from a resource file the only way you can go is just code the child windows creation and allocation by hand.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there is no such form designer which is not part of an external library package. You will have to use a library which has a form designer with it e.g., MFC/ATL/QT etc.

If you are doing pure Win32 application development without any external library, then I am afraid you will have to code everything by hand.